# How to update rows based on one field/column of snowflake tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to update one table using another table on field "Id" such that it wont create duplicates

let say my first table is **Table1** and second table is **Table2** . I would like to update the row in **Table1** from **Table2** when the Id is matching

I am aware of using UNION function but this applies to entire columns where I only need to consider a single column.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#union-all

Example of my Tables

**Table1**

```
Id  name    number  value
1   a        8       100
2   b        8       100
3   c        8       100
4   d        8       100
```

**Table2**

```
Id  name    number  value
3   c         8      99
4   d         6      100
5   e         7      100
```

**Expected output**

```
Id  name    number  value
1   a        8       100
2   b        8       100
3   c        8        99
4   d        6       100
5   e        7       100
```

Please note that in the output table row with Id 3,4 has be updated and new Id 5 is inserted. Can someone help me with the `select query` to get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MERGE command:

```
merge into table1 using table2 on table1.id = table2.id
    when matched then 
        update set table1.name = table2.name, table1.number = table2.number, table1.value = table2.value
    when not matched then 
        insert (Id,name,number,value) values (table2.id, table2.name, table2.number, table2.value);
        
select * from table1;

+----+------+--------+-------+
| ID | NAME | NUMBER | VALUE |
+----+------+--------+-------+
|  5 | e    |      7 |   100 |
|  1 | a    |      8 |   100 |
|  2 | b    |      8 |   100 |
|  3 | c    |      8 |    99 |
|  4 | d    |      6 |   100 |
+----+------+--------+-------+
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

If you don't want to update the table, you may use IFNULL and full outer join:

```
select 
IFNULL( t1.id, t2.id) id,
IFNULL( t2.name, t1.name ) name, 
IFNULL( t2.number, t1.number ) number,
IFNULL( t2.value, t1.value ) value
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id;


+----+------+--------+-------+
| ID | NAME | NUMBER | VALUE |
+----+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | a    |      8 |   100 |
|  2 | b    |      8 |   100 |
|  3 | c    |      8 |    99 |
|  4 | d    |      6 |   100 |
|  5 | e    |      7 |   100 |
+----+------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks!! Is there any way to get that same output using select statement. Without altering the tables

Comment: added to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much!! The solution is pretty good